# Error Installing blender in xp

Tags: installation

I have a PC Dual Core with 4 GB ram. Which version can i install? It must be near the latest and support Windows XP. Please have a link to download. I tried with the lower version 2.75 & 2.76. I have installed with giving error and when i want to uninstall its giving error

The installer has encountered an unexpected error installing this package. this may indicate a problem with the package. The error code is 2753.

How can i proceed. Im stuck in the way.

Comment: Windows XP support ended a few versions ago,not sure exactly which. Try older builds and use the zipped versions, not intallers

Comment: @ duarte thanks for replying after downloading the zip file do i have extract and use or directly from zip file i can use. And with the addon do i have install the addon when ever i open blender zip. or it save

Comment: Most likely you could run latest version if change to, or add,  linux OS.

Comment: Yes, for every new version you would have to manually reinstall your addons unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

I have download the Blender 2.70 a zip file and unzip and using it happily. You can download the previous version from here http://download.blender.org/release/

Comment: could you please stop using "fancy" abbreviations, like "u" instead of "you" and "plz" instead of "please"? BlenderSE is not 4chan or something like that. We're all about quality content here and "cool stuff" might actually be hard to understand for non-native readers (which I consider my self) with less experience in English. Thanks.